# How to connect two nets in verilog (how to connect two physical pins in an FPGA)?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm new to Verilog and I'm trying to connect two physical pins within the FPGA. I have:

```
module top
(
   pin1,
   pin2
);

input pin1;
output pin2;

assign pin2 = pin1;
```

pin1 and pin2 are assigned to physical pins in the constraint file (ucf or xdc).

Is this the right thing to do? Essentially, in my hardware I have pin1 going to the FPGA and pin2 coming out of the FPGA. I want to drive pin2 by pin1.

Thanks,

Comment: pin2 must be an output, as you output a signal. An the term "drive pin2 by pin1" is wrong in this context, as driving means to actual make the electric load, but usually the output blocks of the fpga have drivers on their own. You just want to pass through the signal from the input, not the electrical load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll work, but it depends on what you ultimately want to do/what kind of signals they are/what matters to you.  For example if these are clock signals that's probably not the right way to do it (you should use and ODDR2 flipflop assuming you're in xilinx land or the equivalent in altera).  You should also realize that you're not making an electrical switch per se -- it's a logical switch.

Comment: Thanks. All I want to do is have pin1 and pin2 be connected, as if the FPGA weren't there.